# What does the Bitcoin community need the most now?

Tags: development, project

The Bitcoin project has grown many-fold since its creation, but since we haven't taken over the world yet, there is still some room for growth;). Is there some consensus on what does the Bitcoin project need the most at the current moment? That is, if I had some manpower or money to spend, where would they be best applied to help it grow?

Be it contributing to the main client, developing alternative clients, miners, pools, exchanges, shops, or simply letting more and more people know about the Bitcoins, what are your thoughts on what is the best thing to do?

Comment: While I appreciate the spirit of the question, its answer is likely to be different in a month and so it is too temporally restrained for a StackExchange site.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it would work better on a forum, although then it would be harder to vote on the best answer.

Comment: Most forums (including SMF which bitcointalk.org uses) have polls available. Unfortunately this one is a) too time-constricted and b) more of a discussion-starter than an actual question to belong on a StackExchange site.

Comment: Moved the discussion here if anyone is interested: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=48299.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PR is the most important thing for growth right now.  There's enough basic services that you can use with bitcoin, but not enough people to use them.